# Nautilus icon does not open home directory after 16.04 dist-upgrade

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome, nautilus, icons

By clicking on the nautilus icon in the unity side bar I can open every folder - except my home directory (/home/stefan). If I start nautilus from the command line by typing "nautilus" the home directory opens, in spite of the error message displayed (see below). I own every file in my home directory, I killed nautilus processes, reinstalled nautilus and nautilus-data - everything without results. Does anybody has an idea what to do?

```
stefan@stefan-SATELLITE-C55-A-1P6:~$ nautilus

(nautilus:2678): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed    
(nautilus:2678): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_dbus_interface_skeleton_unexport: assertion 'interface_->priv->connections != NULL' failed    
(nautilus:2678): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed    
(nautilus:2678): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance    
(nautilus:2678): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
```

Comment: try - Unlock current nautilus  icon from launcher. Then Alt+F2 > `nautilus -q` , press enter. Then Alt+F2 > `gtk-launch nautilus`, press enter. Lock that icon to launcher, see how it works

Comment: Thank you, George. Unfortunately it does not work. With Alt+F2 no visible effect. Typing "nautilus -q" in a normal command line produces the error message quoted above. Typing "gtk-launch nautilus" gives me "Initializing nautilus-dropbox 2.10.0" but then nothing happens any more. Nautilus does not open.